# css3 sequential animation for parent and child elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can I make the animation of a child element to occur after the parent has done its animation, i.e. the parent div fades in then its child element fades in 1 second later?

I have tried many tricks but nothing works, the child element is still fading at the same time as the parent.

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/oeLbh43o/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <h1>The Title Here</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.parent h1 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.parent:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.parent:hover h1 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using CSS transitions so you should indicate `transition-delay` instead of `animation-delay`.

```css
.parent {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}

.parent h1 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0;
    transition-delay: 0;
}

.parent:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0;
    transition-delay: 0;
}
.parent:hover h1 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>The Title Here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @MatthewG. What about the reverse, when on `mouseleave`, i.e. the child element should fade out before the parent get smaller again?

Comment: In this case, you want to also indicate the transition-delays for the non-hovered state.  So make sure you reverse which one has no delay and which one has some delay.  See my answer, I have updated it to give you this example.